# how to execute an exe with variable value for path and arguments

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute in my powershell script the command below :

```
D:\Apps\Documentum\product\7.3\bin\idql.exe -udmadmin -pPassword dctm04 -RC:\temp\documentum\session_list.txt -w20 > C:\temp\documentum\session_logstash.txt
```

In my powershell script I do that:

```
$DOCBASE="dctm04"
$USER_DOCBASE="dmadmin"
$USER_PWD="Password01"
$IDQL_PATH="D:\Apps\Documentum\product\7.3\bin"
$QRY_SESSIONS="C:\temp\documentum\session_list.txt"
$QRY_LOG_SESSIONS="C:\temp\documentum\session_logstash.txt"

$IDQL_PATH\idql.exe -u$USER_DOCBASE -p$USER_PWD $DOCBASE -R$QRY_SESSIONS -w20 > $QRY_LOG_SESSIONS
```

But it doesn't work properly, I receive the error below :

```
At C:\temp\documentum\Generate.ps1:49 char:13
+   $IDQL_PATH\idql.exe -u$USER_DOCBASE -p$USER_PWD $DOCBASE -R$QRY_SESSIONS -w20  ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\idql.exe' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I think, i don't use variable properly on my command.

Please note my powershell version is :

```
PS C:\temp\documentum> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

could you give me the solution in order to solve my problem

Comment: Please edit the question and add more details. What, exactly, does " it doesn't work properly" mean? Nothing happens? An error message appears? Wrong results?

Comment: How does it not work properly? What error messages are you getting? What version of PowerShell are you using? Are you using the ISE, or the console? Are you running as Administrator, or as an ordinary user? There's a whole host of information you need to provide before we can be of any help to you...

Comment: ok I added more informations to my question

Comment: What about using `Join-Path` and/or `Test-Path` to assure the file exists?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason is that combining a string to executable name makes no sense to Powershell's parsing rules. Use the call operator `&` or `Invoke-Item`. Like so,

```
$ssms="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio"
PS C:\> $ssms\ssms.exe
At line:1 char:6
+ $ssms\ssms.exe
+      ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\ssms.exe' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

C:\>& $ssms\ssms.exe
# Launches SSMS succesfully

C:\>Invoke-Item $ssms\ssms.exe
# Launches SSMS succesfully
```

There's [nice a document](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx) about running executables.